# Designer is not loading when i am trying to create a metro style in visual studio 2011 in windows 8

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-8

I get the following error message on the design screen:

```
An unhandled exception has occured
Details:
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[2108] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IIsolationDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String assemblyCodeBase, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedExportProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateExportProvider(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, ICatalogFactory catalogFactory, IExportFilter filter)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateDesignerViewInfo(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationTokenSource cancelSource)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.DesignerViewWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass54.<EnsureViewTask>b__52()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

The above link is dead but I [found a page](http://www.expressionblend.com/articles/2012/03/07/known-issue-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio-11-beta-crashes-on-launch/) that referred to the link and will copy the steps here:

```
* Shut down all running instances of Visual Studio.
* Launch a command prompt as an Administrator.
* Type the following in sequence:
    pushd %VS110COMNTOOLS%
    icacls ..\IDE /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(F)
    icacls ..\IDE /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(CI)(F)
    icacls ..\IDE\PrivateAssemblies /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(F)
    icacls ..\IDE\PrivateAssemblies /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(CI)(F)
    icacls ..\IDE\PublicAssemblies /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(F)
    icacls ..\IDE\PublicAssemblies /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(CI)(F)
* Restart Visual Studio and try your scenario again.
```

That being said, this didn't solve my particular problem which was similar but not quite the same as this one. Perhaps this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I face this confusing error too. Drop a TextBox in a page, and voila.. I got the unstyled dialog box saying error as explained in this page : [[3028] Designer process terminated unexpectedly! Unable to load xaml designer pages](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732656/3028-designer-process-terminated-unexpectedly-unable-to-load-xaml-designer-pages). The solution? after dropping the control, try rebuild the solution. CTRL+SHIFT+B

Works for me!

- Now I can continue solving this task of mine ;)